# MySQL date comparison filter

Tags: mysql, datetime, filter

I have some SQL code that works great and returns the desired results from my Wordpress database.

However, I simply cannot get my head around how to filter dates between say:

```
2010-12-10 00:00:00
```

and

```
2010-12-15 00:00:00
```

Here is my SQL code:

```
$SQL_K =  "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.* 
             FROM wp_posts 
             JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id)
            WHERE 1 = 1 
              AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' 
              AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') 
              AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'expiry_date' 
         GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 
         ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC 
            LIMIT 0, 100 ";
```

Comment: How do you call the 15th month of the year?

Comment: 2010-15-10 doesn't match the YYYY-MM-DD format that MySQL accepts by default, so I'd fix such instances in order to be able to use MySQL date related functionality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
WHERE date_column BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('2010-12-10', '%Y-%m-%d') AND STR_TO_DATE('2010-12-15', '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Like so?

*EDIT: forgot a closing quote. oops*

*EDITv2: Adding your code with the updated query*

*EDITv3: little optimization*
removed 1=1 comparison, uses IN() for wp_posts.post_status

```
SELECT      SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.* 
FROM        wp_posts 
  JOIN      wp_postmeta 
  ON        (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id) 
WHERE       wp_posts.post_type = 'post' 
  AND       (wp_posts.post_status IN ('publish','private'))
  AND       wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'expiry_date' 
  AND       ___INSERT_NAME_OF_DATE_COLUMN_HERE___
    BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('2010-12-05', '%Y-%m-%d')
      AND   STR_TO_DATE('2010-12-15', '%Y-%m-%d')
GROUP BY    wp_posts.ID 
ORDER BY    wp_posts.post_date DESC 
LIMIT       0, 100
```

Comment: thanks mate, I get no results now (my fault though of coarse): 

$SQL_K =  "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id) WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'expiry_date' WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'expiry_date' BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('2010-12-05', '%Y-%m-%d') AND STR_TO_DATE('2010-12-15', '%Y-%m-%d') GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 100 ";

Comment: I see a duplicate WHERE in there. Try removing that and replacing it with an `AND`. I was showing the WHERE clause for the sake of placement, not syntax. ;-)

Comment: Brad, thanks ever so much for your code and help. The results show now, but if I change the dates to between 2010-12-06 - 2010-12-08 (among others), the same results show etc and aren't being filtered.. So close

Comment: Heh, missed it myself. What's the name of the column you're trying to compare. I just ntoiced the above is filtering a `wp_postmeta.meta_key` (which is also already being compared). Replace the `wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'expiry_date'` with the name of the column that possesses the date you're filtering by.

Comment: Or, in reference to the above, change `___INSERT_NAME_OF_DATE_COLUMN_HERE___` to that specific column.

Comment: Why are you using str_to_date?  CCYY-MM-DD is MySQL's native format, all you're doing is removing any chance of using an index.

Comment: @PMV: I saw comments that insinuated the date could be in a different format & was trying to accommodate. MySQL is natively calling this method anyways, this just gives a more explicit declaration and a visual queue of what the comparison's looking for.

Comment: Never knew mysql called STR_TO_DATE, but it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

```
use between date1 and date2
```