# How can I retrieve photos in database according to it's date?

Tags: php, database

I'm still learning to program and I challenge my self to create slideshow retrieving images according to it's date. Thank you in response.

Comment: Start with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412257/mysql-date-comparison-filter

Comment: Not much of a challenge if you want us to do it for you. What do you have so far and where are you stuck specifically?

Comment: Im nearly done but retrieving images according to it's date is confusing and a bit hard for still learning like me.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear information about this question, I just need idea or information about my prob. Thanks!

Comment: What database? Any kind of SQL? SQL has ORDER BY keyword: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly ? (according to its date = latest dates, given dates ?) What have you done exactly, do you already have a query ? For MySql, Postgresql ?

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch pic from database like this

```
SELECT * FROM `pic`  ORDER BY time ASC
```

Order by will give you the result as you want, make sure you have a time attribute in the table.

and you have to just loop through the return data and display as you want